Error while login to Telegram test servers (PHONE_CODE_INVALID)
Got an error "You have entered an invalid code" when trying to login to telegram test server
Trying to do it throught Win Desktop client and from gramjs api
Trying to sign in f.e. 9996611502 number with code 11111
In code using such function
async authTestUser(phoneNumber: string, code: number, user = "User One") {
        let stringSession = new StringSession("");
        let telegramTestDC = {
            dcId: 3,
            ip: "149.154.175.117",
            // dcId: 2,
            // ip: "149.154.167.40",
            // dcId: 1,
            // ip: "149.154.175.10",
            port: 443,
        }
        stringSession.setDC(
            telegramTestDC.dcId,
            telegramTestDC.ip,
            telegramTestDC.port
        );
        this.client = new TelegramClient(stringSession, apiId, apiHash, {
            testServers: true,
            connectionRetries: 5,
            requestRetries: 10,
        });
        await this.client.start({
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            phoneCode: async () => { return code.toString() },
            firstAndLastNames: async () => { return [`First name ${user}`, `Last name ${user}`] },
            onError: (err: any) => {
                throw new Error(`Error in authTestUser: For ${phoneNumber}. ${err}`);
            },
        });
        this.clientSessionString = await this.client.session.save();
        console.log(this.clientSessionString);
        return this.client;
    }

and got Error
Error in authTestUser: For +9996611502. RPCError: 400: PHONE_CODE_INVALID (caused by auth.SignIn)

Want to login telegram test servers

This seems to be an issue caused by Telegram itself. Other users are reporting the same behavior on GitHub. Did you find a solution yet?

Still haven't got any fix or workaround. And were did you saw any reporting for this problem?

Here are several people reporting the same issue https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/3083
